# Rotate proxy in k6 script

Tags: javascript, linux, load-testing, http-proxy, k6

I know you can set a single proxy with an environment variable to a K6 script like this:

```
HTTP_PROXY="user:pass@x.x.x.x.:yyyyy" k6 run script.js
```

I also tried changing the value (randomly) of `HTTP_PROXY` inside the script and it changes successfully inside the script with `console.log( )`, But the `HTTP_PROXY` remains the same in the k6 result, In the target server, it only shows the proxy I passed through the environment variable.

This is the simplified version of the script:

```
import http from 'k6/http';
import {
    check
} from 'k6';
import {
    SharedArray
} from 'k6/data';

// Reads a list of http proxies in json format
export const proxies = new SharedArray('proxies', function() {
  const f = JSON.parse(open('./proxies.json'));
  return f;
});

// Generates a random number in a given range
function RandomRange(min, max) {
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min);
}

export default function () {

    // Set to random from a list of proxies
    __ENV.HTTP_PROXY = proxies[RandomRange(0, proxies.length)].proxy;

    // This line shows that proxies are changing
    console.log(__ENV.HTTP_PROXY);

    const res = http.get('http://some-random-server.com/index.php');

    check(res, {
        'Status is 200': (r) => r.status === 200,
        'Resp includes': (r) => r.body.includes('success'),
    });
}
```

Is there a workaround for changing/rotating the proxy for every `vu` or `http_req` or `iteration`?

Comment: You currently can't change the HTTP proxy dynamically, you can only specify it globally for the whole test run. This is something that we plan to fix in the future, though it's not a very high priority and I can't make any promises when that will happen. Follow https://github.com/grafana/k6/issues/1045 for updates.

For now, I'd suggest using an xk6 extension to work around this, see https://k6.io/docs/extensions/guides/create-an-extension/

Comment: @na-- So dynamic changing is not possible even when I'm able to change proxy inside the script. It seems I have to use a local proxy rotator.

Comment: Yes, that is probably the simplest way to go about it for now